# VBA to copy specific sheet to existing book

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet, copying

The task here is two fold (the first part already works though).
Task 1: Copy a sheet that's been selected from a combo box into a new document.
Task 2: Copy a specific sheet from the original document and add it to the new document that was created above.

So far I've got this: (but the second task doesn't work)

```
Sub Extract()

Dim wbkOriginal As Workbook
Set wbkOriginal = ActiveWorkbook



'sets site and engineer details into the estate page that is being extracted
Worksheets(FrontPage.CmbSheet.Value).Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("E6")
Worksheets(FrontPage.CmbSheet.Value).Range("D3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("N6")
Worksheets(FrontPage.CmbSheet.Value).Range("F3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("K6")
Worksheets(FrontPage.CmbSheet.Value).Range("B4").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("F8")
Worksheets(FrontPage.CmbSheet.Value).Range("D4").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("K8")

' copies sheet name from combo box into new document, saves it with site name and current date
' into C:\Temp\ folder for ease of access

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(FrontPage.CmbSheet.Value)
    .Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
            "C:\temp\" _
            & .Cells(3, 2).Text _
            & " " _
            & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY") _
            & ".xlsm", _
            xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, , , , False
        End With

Dim wbkExtracted As Workbook

Set wbkExtracted = ActiveWorkbook

 Workbooks(wbkOriginal.Name).Sheets(DOCUMENTS).Copy _
    After:=Workbooks(wbkExtracted.Name).Sheets(wbkExtracted.Name).Sheets.Count

'code to close the original workbook to prevent accidental changes etc
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'wbkOriginal.Close
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I'm hoping one of you clever folks out there can tell me what I'm doing wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Full_Extract()

Dim wbkOriginal As Workbook
Set wbkOriginal = ActiveWorkbook

'sets site and engineer details into the estate page that is being extracted
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("E6")
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("D3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("N6")
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("F3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("K6")
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("B4").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("F8")
Worksheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Range("D4").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("K8")

' copies sheet name from combo box into new document, saves it with site name and current date
' into C:\Temp\ folder for ease of access

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array((Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value), "Z-MISC"))
            .Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
            "C:\temp\" _
            & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value).Cells(3, 2).Text _
            & " " _
            & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY") _
            & ".xlsm", _
            xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, , , , False
        End With

'code to close the original workbook to prevent accidental changes etc
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbkOriginal.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the problem you are running into. (Maybe) If you are working with a new instance of excel you need to save it then reopen it. It must have something to do with the object model. I had to do this not too long ago. Here is a snippet of the code I used.

```
Set appXL = New Excel.application
appXL.Workbooks.Add
Set wbThat = appXL.ActiveWorkbook
wbThat.application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbThat.SaveAs Filename:=strFilePath & "\" & strFileName

'This code needed to allow the copy function to work
wbThat.Close savechanges:=True
Set wbThat = Nothing
Set wbThat = application.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath & "\" & strFileName)
appXL.Quit
Set appXL = Nothing

'Copy Help page from this workbook to the report
wbThis.Sheets("Help").Copy after:=wbThat.Sheets(wbThat.Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: Hi Jack - thanks (delayed I know, sorry, got distracted by other work). Back onto this topic again and I'm struggling to get your code idea to work in my particular scenario.

I decided to backtrack and try a different approach, using an array instead. And I'm getting some better progress.

Comment: Now I'm getting a run-time error of 438, "Object doesn't support this property or method" - it creates the new book, and moves the sheet selected from the drop down, plus the supporting documents sheet, but regardless of how I specify the array, it ALWAYS puts the documents sheet first, and what I think is causing the problem is when it queries the cells (3,2) for the cell data (which is what specifies the first part of the file name) because the ZON-DOCS sheet is first in the new book, there's no data in those cells. And thus it falls over. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hah, or not, just tested that theory by manually inserting some data into the referenced cell. No joy.

Comment: ```With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array((Sheet1.CmbSheet.Value), "ZON-DOCS"))
    .Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
            "C:\temp\" _
            & .Cells(3, 2).Text _
            & " " _
            & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY") _
            & ".xlsm", _
            xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, , , , False
        End With```